# How to call the .removeAllFiles() function in Dropzone.js after a click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the http://www.dropzonejs.com/ (dropzone.js) library. I have initialized one of my form element as,

```
   var drop = $("#upload").dropzone({
                uploadMultiple: "true",
                addRemoveLinks: "true",
                thumbnailWidth: "250",
                thumbnailHeight: "250",
                maxFilesize: "10",
                headers: {
                    "title": titles,
                    "location": locations,
                    "tag": tags
                    }                   
            });
```

Now when user clicks on a `<button id="close"></button>` button, I want to empty the whole list using the `drop.removeAllFiles(true)` function, as suggested on Dropzone.js official website.

So, I tried using

```
 $("#close").click(function(){
      drop.removeAllFiles(true);
   });
```

But it's not working, In `console.log` I am getting the error `removeAllFiles() is not declared for drop`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: is there any error in the browser console

Comment: yeah when I click on the "#close" button, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'removeAllFiles' ".

Answer (score 59):

This worked for me.

```
Dropzone.forElement("#YourDropBoxId").removeAllFiles(true);
```

Reference: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/180

Comment: Great! Thanks Ducain

Comment: Nice!! saved my time

Comment: You sir, are my hero!

Answer (score 11):

Here is the code, it will solve your problem.

```
$(function() {
            Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { 
            init: function () {
                var myDropZone = this;
                $("#btnRemoveAll").click(function () {
                            myDropZone.removeAllFiles();
                        }
                );
            }

        };
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `drop` is referencing the jQuery object instead of the Dropzone object.

```
var drop = $("#upload").dropzone(options);
```

Sometimes it is necessary to use [jQuery(selector [,context])](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) with dropzone. So the non-jquery constructor is not as convenient.

```
var drop = new Dropzone(selector, options);
```

Instead, you can get the Dropzone object with *(the ugly)*:

```
var drop = $("#upload").dropzone(options).get(0).dropzone;

$("#close").click(function(){
    drop.removeAllFiles(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working...Please try this.

```
$("#close").click(function(){
    drop.removeAllFiles(true);
});
$("#upload").dropzone({
            uploadMultiple: "true",
            addRemoveLinks: "true",
            thumbnailWidth: "250",
            thumbnailHeight: "250",
            maxFilesize: "10",
            headers: {
                "title": titles,
                "location": locations,
                "tag": tags
                },
            init: function () {
       var dropzone = this;
       $("#close").click(function(){
  dropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
});
    }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This also includes JSON calls to the server for deleting the files.

```
mydropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone",{
    url: "/dropzone",
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    maxFilesize: 2.0,
    dictResponseError: 'Error uploading file!',
    removedfile: function(file) {
        var name = {file: file.name}
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/dropzone_delete',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(name),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (e) {console.log(e);}
        });
        var _ref;
        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    }   
});

// Clear all files
$("#btn_clear_dropzone").click(function () {
    // Delete existing files
    mydropzone.removeAllFiles();
    // Cancel current uploads
    mydropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
});
```

Please let me know if people have suggestions to further refine this code.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable at the top of the scripts

```
var drpzone;
```

Assign `this` to the `drpzone` in `init`.

```
$("#upload").dropzone({
            
            //your other options,
            init: function () {
                 drpzone = this;
           }
});
```

And use `drpzone.removeAllFiles()` in your custom event

```
$("#close").click(function(){
    drpzone.removeAllFiles();
});
```

final code:

```
var drpzone;
$("#upload").dropzone({
            
            //your other options,
            init: function () {
                 drpzone = this;
           }
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    drpzone.removeAllFiles();
});
```

It is better to have this operation inside `$(document).ready()`.