# onclick clear dropzone file field

Tags: jquery, html, dropzone.js

I'm using [`dropzonejs`](http://www.dropzonejs.com). My `HTML` is as follows:

```
<div class="dropzone" id="upload1"></div>
<script>
$("#upload1").dropzone({
    url: "upload.php?frm=logo",
    paramName: "post_ipfld",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop Files or Select",
    success: function(file, response) {
        $("#id").val($.trim(response));
        ////////// Save the values in db
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php?frm=new",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#frm_save").serialize(),
            success: function(d) {
                $("#pid").val($.trim(d));
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

The above is working fine. The problem is that I have a clear link in the end of the form. By clicking this clear link I need to clear some form fields but I can't get it to clear my dropzone field.

I am successfully clearing the form fields like this:

```
$('#fld1, #fld2, #fld5').val('');
```

To clear the dropzone I tried this:

```
var myDropzone = $("#upload1").dropzone();
myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
$('div.dz-image').remove();
```

How do I use `removeAllFiles()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two resources you should check out:

- https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Remove-all-files-with-one-button
- [How to call the .removeAllFiles() function in Dropzone.js after a click on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460695/how-to-call-the-removeallfiles-function-in-dropzone-js-after-a-click-on-a-but)

Basically, you need to add this `init` variable to your settings object and set a variable in the appropriate scope. It will create a function called `clearDropzone` which should do what you expect.

```
var clearDropzone;
$("#upload1").dropzone({
    init: function () {
        var dropzone = this;
        clearDropzone = function(){
            dropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
        };
    },
    url: "save.php?frm=new",
    /* etc. */
}
```